# ViewBag value becomes null in the post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in Edit get method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    Event e = await db.Events.FindAsync(id);
    ViewBag.OldCategories = e.Categories.ToList(); 
    // ViewBag.OldCategories is not null (tested in VS quick viewer)
```

And I have the following code in the post method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,....,Categories")] EventCreateViewModel eventVm)
{
    var oldCategories = ViewBag.OldCategories; // Null
```

However, the oldCategories is always null in the post method. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3):

ViewBag is only accessible in View  when you set it from controller, when form is posted ViewBag values are removed, if you want the values to be accessible in form post you can post them via hidden fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyHidden" value="@ViewBag.AnyKey"/>
```

or other way around is to use **TempData**, instead of placing in viewbag, place data in **TempData** and remember TempData is once read, means once you read its value it will be removed from **TempData**, you can retain it by calling `TempData.Keep()`

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
 TempData["myKey"] = "";
}
```

and View:

```
@{

string value = TempData["myKey"] as stirng;

TempData.Keep("myKey") // retains value in TempData

}
```

Comment: I tried to change `ViewBag.OldCategories` to `TempData["OldCategories"]` and it behaved the same. Should I add `TempData.Keep("OldCategories")` in the view to retain it in the post method?

Comment: Use keep to persist it in tempdata

Answer (score 0):

Once the View is rendered with Razor, the ViewBag is emptied. It's only good for one trip to the client, and then it's wiped. If you want to be able to read it back in your Controller when the client calls back to the server, you'll need to use `TempData` instead.

Even if you do a `Redirect()` inside a Controller Action, your ViewBag data will be lost, because you're moving onto a second page, and out of the scope of ViewBag.

Comment: Or, you could fill a hidden variable in your page with the viewbag or model value and have it when they post the page.

Comment: Right. That's another (more conventional) way of doing this. I was just following along with his paradigm. The variable looks as though it could be a (possibly large) collection, so having lots of inputs to copy back and forth could be cumbersome.